# Why can't owner create folder in masterpage of SharePoint Online trial?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have succeeded create a map network drive from my computer to my SharePoint Online site using the option "Connect using different credentials".[image]
However, when I tried to create a folder in this map drive, then something went wrong although the user have full control and contribute permissions in SharePoint.[image]

Could anyone help me or give a suggestion for this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the mapped network drive->Properties->Sharing->Share->you can set the permission for the folder.

[image]

Besides, make sure the user has permission on the master page in SharePoint online.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why but I can't find Sharing tab when choose Properties.